# Want to extract .js link from webpage

Tags: java, javascript

I want to extract .js link from a webpage . How can I find the link of a javascript page from the source code of web page.

I want my answer in java prospective.

Comment: I can think of three separate things that you could mean by ".js link". Please be more specific, ideally with examples.

Comment: It would also be worth showing some effort - where did you get stuck? Getting the HTML? Parsing it? Searching it? Getting the data out of a found node? Something else?

Comment: I mean those .js file that are necessary to show a complete web-page.

Comment: That still isn't completely clear. Are you trying to get the URIs of the JavaScript files? (That's my best guess as to what you are looking for but I'm not certain). Are you trying to get the HTML of the complete webpage after any JavaScript linked to it has been executed?

Comment: I am using cobra html parser . but I could not find any suitable method to find the link or image. Then I try to search the source code manually

Comment: Why didn't you say you were using Cobra in the question? What image? You didn't mention an image before.

Comment: I am not having problems with downloading images. only .js links

Comment: You still haven't made it clear what you mean by ".js link".

Comment: to run a webpage completely which js file are required

Comment: To **run** one? Does that mean you want to get a DOM after JavaScript has run over it (so that you can extract data from it), or that you want to (effectively) build a web browser?

Comment: I simply want to download a webpage with its full content

Comment: In that case, simply downloading the .js is not going to help.  I might have been inclined to help more, but ... see above.

Comment: So you want to download the HTML document, and every file that it references (other then links to different documents), and every file that they reference (recursively, since CSS could @import more CSS that could have background images), and then just save all the files to disk?

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: That's the problem I'm having with your question. Step back from the problem and explain what you are trying to achieve (ideal from the perspective of someone who is using the script you are writing - what do they put in, what do they get out?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try an [HTML parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Well you'd have to parse the file yourself :) You could write something that scans the file for `<script type="text/javascript"` but it's more error-prone, since a page could skip the "type" attribute, or use two spaces instead of one, split the string on two lines, and so on

Comment: Novice programmers always believe using a library is harder than writing it themselves - they don't realize how many hours of work fixing bugs and edge cases writing the library took...

Comment: I want to use library but don't find any suitable one . If you know then help me.